# Can I parse my latest facebook status using php?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm a newbie programmer who's learning php. And i've set out on my latest adventure of pulling my latest facebook status update and displaying the text on a personal webpage that I have.

It seems that facebook has gotten rid of the status update RSS feed, so I don't have that to pull from anymore. So, it appears that i'll have to make my facebook status updates public in order for them to be grabbed by the php code.

Does anyone know anything about this and how to accomplish it?

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use this? http://www.facebook.com/badges/

Comment: Have a look on this tutorial **[Facebook PHP Tutorial](http://www.merchantos.com/blog/makebeta/facebook/facebook-php-tutorial)** Also download **Facebook API (PHP)** here and have a look at examples <https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/> Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing data from facebook pages is illegal. All information you're allowed to retrieve you have to get using [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

In your specific case you could do that using this API endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<username>/feed?access_token=...
```

Comment: In his case I think he would be looking for `/statuses`